# Can't run perforce commands in command line

Tags: python, command-line, command-prompt, perforce, p4v

I have two tickets currently open and also tried to run a command when only one was open but no luck either way. One ticket is the administrator the other is my personal account.

Logging in works fine however when I try to run this command I found [here](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2543)

```
p4 user -d -f user_name
```

And the response I get is "Your session has expired, please login again."

I am trying to write a script in python to delete a list of users, but I first need to know what commands to run to delete the users in a command line window.

Comment: What is your question? How to manage multiple identities? How to know when you need to re-login? How to delete a user? How to write a script in Python? Remember how to ask a useful question: present the full code you've written, show the full output you've received, include the details, be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what "two tickets open" means and it makes me think you're doing something excessively tricky.  If you run this in one command prompt:

```
p4 set P4USER=your_admin_user
p4 set P4PASSWD=
p4 login
p4 user -d -f user_name
```

that should do the trick -- my best guesses as to why you're getting a "ticket expired" after login are that you have an old ticket set in P4PASSWD and it's overriding your P4TICKETS file, or you've got multiple windows open at once and you're swapping between users and you're confused about what user you're trying to connect as.  Either way, the above sequence of commands should work if you run it in one place.